# Problem with constants in application.ini after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've upgraded PHP on my local dev system to version 5.3.0, and there is some problem when I use constants in application.ini - following manual http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html I have:

```
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
```

which leads to:

```
Warning: require_once(APPLICATION_PATH/Bootstrap.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Zend\Application.php on line 320
```

any ideas?

---

SOLVED:

Actually name of my constant was _DIR_APPLICATION (code above was copied from ZF manual) - problem lies in this underscore at the begining - it seems that parse_ini_file() in PHP 5.3.0 doesn't replace constants named like this.

Short test - you need two files:

test.ini

```
bootstrap.path = _DIR_APPLICATION "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
```

and test.php

```
<?php

define('_DIR_APPLICATION', 'test');

$data = parse_ini_file('test.ini');
print_r($data);
```

try to run, then change constant name to 'DIR_APPLICATION' (in both files) and compare result ;)

Comment: and when I switch back to 5.2.11 everything works ok

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to a change to 'open_basedir' in php 5.3.0

cf. http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

the open_basedir value may be set in your httpd.conf, in the php.ini or at runtime with ini_set().
I'd recommand to take a look at this value with phpinfo(), comparing between the 2 versions of PHP you're using.

Comment: in both versions:

    open_basedir => no value